# The name '"function" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, compiler-errors

this is my scenario:
I'm working on asp project, and i'm using javascript in it, too.
So, in the .cs file of my asp page I have some function that I call using javascript in this way:

```
`var variable = '<%=GetIt("hi") %>';`
```

and it works.
But, after, I added a new function

```
 `public static string mergeThem(a,b){....}`
```

That is called in the same way but, when I compile:

> CS0103: The name 'mergeThem' does not exist in the current context

**So, Why?**

Comment: On what row do you get this exception? Please provide a little more detail. I would bet it is because you are declaring it static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.Net code alway reference to the isntance of the ASP.Net-C#-Class, so you can't use static, because it is not accessable over the instance.